# Фраза "Проблемы индейцев шерифа не волнуют"

Tags: фразеология

Последнее время часто слышу фразу "Проблемы индейцев шерифа не волнуют". Смысл достаточно понятен, но откуда она взялась в нашей речи? Поиск в ин-те как-то не помог найти историю происхождения.

Comment: Появилось стойкое ощущение, что фраза переводная. Англоязычная. Если кто зарегистрирован на Тупичке у Д.Ю. Пучкова просьба, не в службу, а в дружбу, задать ему этот вопрос. Он может знать по причине своей профессиональной деятельности (переводы разговорной речи).

Comment: Я не соображу, кто такой этот Д. Ю. Пучков, но я пытался надыбать что-то на анлийский манер гуглом. Увы, никаких следов. Впрочем, часто случается, что в переводе фраза употребляется гораздо чаще, чем на языке оригинала.

Comment: >  Впрочем, часто случается, что в переводе фраза употребляетс ягораздо чаще, чем в на языке оригинала.   

Точно! Говорят, такая же история была с фразой "Знание - сила", которую приписывают Бэкону (не помню уж, Р. или Ф.) Англичане ее не знали. Потом на одноименном журнале поменяли английский вариант: "Knowledge _itself_ is power".

Comment: Д.Ю. Пучков (Гоблин) - переводчик фильмов. Я бы ещё добавила бывший милиционер и сантехник. Есть у него сайт "Тупичок" http://oper.ru/, но он достаточно суров и задавать вопрос ему я боюсь. Опять же, регистрироваться надо.

Comment: Тьфу, склероз проклятый. ))) Спасибо. Гоблин - это понятно. 
И про тупичок, вспоминаю, слышал, хотя туда и не вхож.

>приписывают Бэкону (не помню уж, Р. или Ф.)
    
Роджеру, конечно. Френсис - это совершенно другая эпоха и совершенно другая философия.  
Касательно самой фразы... Тут немного другое. Её, фразу, видимо, до сих пор неправильно истолковывают, кто бы ни был автором. Добавление itself тут не слишком помогает. Хотя это тоже обычная история, половина, если не более, классических афоризмов переосмыслена. Но это отдельный разговор.

Comment: В фильме Серебристая пыль нет такой фразы. Я специально его пересмотрела для проверки.

Answer (score 3):

Есть смутные воспоминания, что в оригинале фраза звучит как "Проблемы индейцев вождя не волнуют" и принадлежит она О. Генри. Первое имеет подтверждение в словарях арго, за последнее совсем не ручаюсь.

Answer (score 0):

А искали Вы где? На первой странице google нашел следующий анекдот, претендующий на роль первоисточника:

> Листок-обращение администрации пивного
> бара в туалете: "Убедительная просьба
> не засорять унитаз. Сантехник
> измучался прочищать!" 
> Чуть ниже,
> другими чернилами: "Проблемы негра
> Шерифа не волнуют!"

Comment: В лугом месте на этот вопрос давался тот же ответ. Но один из пользователей написал так: "Гыгы. Все дружно нагуглили один и тот же тупой анекдот, в котором использована за уши притянутая крылатая фраза, настоящее происхождение которой никто не помнит". Может, он и прав.  

Кстати, поисковик на данный запрос дал еще информацию:  
когда ковбои разговаривают, кони обычно молчат

Comment: Анекдот нашла, но как-то смутил он меня. Кстати, появился чисто академический вопрос: можно ли назвать анекдоты народной мудростью наравне с пословицами и поговорками старины? Многие их них, проверенные временем, так и живут в речи.

Comment: Да и в анекдоте "проблема НЕГРА", я слышу "Проблемы индейцев шерифа не волнуют". Допускаю, что со временем смысл оттачивается на более прикладной что ли.

Comment: Я ошиблась, на том сайте было два анекдота, прчем большинство привело именно про индейца (он вбежал с гранатой к шерифу). Но мысль, что фраза была ДО анекдота кажется мне правдоподобной.

Comment: Хотела своими словами сказать, но не смогу так исчерпывающе, как в словаре (сокращаю, а то не хв. симв.):   

Б. толк. словарь
АНЕКДОТ [от греч. anekdotos - неопубликованный].
1.
**Один из жанров фольклора**: короткий юмористический рассказ, обычно высмеивающий кого-, что-л. А. про кого-, что-л. Насмешить анекдотом. Солдатские, сальные анекдоты.
2. Разг.
Необычное происшествие, событие. Скверный, неприятный а. произошёл с кем-л. Вот какой а. случился со мной. ->энц. Первоначально: занимательный или поучительный рассказ из жизни исторического лица, легендарного героя и т.п. < Анекдотец, -тца.

Comment: '__inna__', а какое это имеет отноешние к вопросу?
Кстати, как вам удалось запатентовать ник, котрый не воспринимается редактором?

Answer (score 0):

Bethemotus почти прав. "Проблемы индейцев *вождя* не волнуют" -  фраза из советского фильма 1953 года "Серебристая пыль", снятого по пьесе эстонского писателя Аугуста Якобсона "Шакалы". Умный фильм.

Comment: Хорошо бы, конечно, иметь пруфлинк какой-нибудь.  Попробую связаться с друзьями в Эстонии, они должны бы знать... Но даже если принять на веру, то  дело-то в том, что выражение явно не советское. Я его и на английском слышал.

Answer (score 0):

Ещё говорят наоборот:
*Проблемы шерифа индейцев не волнуют!*